# union of columns in standard sql

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables (`A` and `B`) with different columns and the same number of rows. I would like to get a new table with the union of all columns using Google's standard SQL.

Is there a simpler way than creating a pseudo column (`idx`) using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` and do a join?

```
WITH
A_EXT AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() idx FROM `myproject.A`),
B_EXT AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() idx FROM `myproject.B`)
SELECT * EXCEPT(idx) FROM 
  A_EXT JOIN B_EXT 
  USING (idx)
```

For comparison, this is how simple this is with pandas

```py
pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```

and it is even simpler in q/kdb+

```
A ,' B
```

Comment: what is the joining logic? just any from A to any from B?

Comment: First row to the first row, second to the second, etc. We can assume there are time stamp columns in both tables and we can order by this column.

Comment: and those timestamps are not matching? so you cannot join by that timestamp - right? if so, what you have is your option - assuming you add ORDER BY inside OVER. unless you hit issue with ROW_NUMBER() (depends on how big your data row-wise)- in this case show us the issue so we can help resolve it

Comment: Yes, we cannot assume that the times match. Btw. i described the original problem in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741959/weighted-sum-of-a-column-vector-and-a-derived-bit-vector and i get a solution that specifies price and size columns by index (e.g. first four columns store the prices). I need a solution in which i can specify the price and size columns by column name. The original table may contain extra columns and the price and size columns may occur in any order.

Comment: so, post your new question (as I already suggested you) and we will answer it. :o)

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859620/weighted-sum-of-a-column-vector-and-a-derived-bit-vector-version-2

Comment: see the answer there